# Защита серверной части php

Tags: php

У меня есть серверная часть написанная на php, мне нужно её максимально защитить от XSS и подобных атак.

Код:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);

$vs = $_GET["bb"];
echo $vs;

$hash = "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592";

if (isset($vs)) {
    if ($vs != $hash) {
        header("Connection: close");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Succ";
    }
}

echo "Tralala";

?>
```

Сервер: `localhost`
Меня не устраивает то, что если юзер перейдет не на `localhost/test/?bb=` , а допустим на `localhost/test/` не введя при этом аргументов, php код продолжит выполнятся. То есть у меня выведется `Tralala`, которое никаким боков не должно вывестись, а соединение должно быть уже разорванным. Как эту проблему исправить? Ведь как я знаю это что-то на подобие серверной уязвимости.

Comment: Ну, дописать ещё один else для условия isset?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);

$vs = $_GET["bb"];
echo $vs;

$hash = "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592";

if (isset($vs)) {
    if ($vs != $hash) {
        header("Connection: close");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Succ";
    }
}
else
{
    exit("Wrong Url");
}

echo "Tralala";

?>
```

Comment: Просьба минусующим - [обосновывайте свои минусы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Спасибо.